# I can't explain the result of the following output

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to read source code of jQuery but some basic concept stops me.
To make it simple, I write the following code, but the output turn out to be weird.

```
function Foo(){
}
var foo = new Foo();
var foo2 = new Foo();

console.log(Foo.toString == Foo.prototype.toString); // false
console.log(foo.toString === Foo.toString); // false
console.log(foo.toString == foo2.toString); // true
```

I can't tell why the first and the second are false. I've learned that any custom object must inherit Object, and I didn't override toString method at all, but why foo.toString !== Foo.toString !== Foo.prototype.toString  ???

Comment: Not a javascript expert but I believe `.toString` is a function and should be used as `.toString()`

Answer (score 1):

The first two are `false` because you are comparing a method of a **function** against a method of an **object**.
That would not be a problem by itself, but functions override `toString`. So essentially, you are comparing `Function.prototype.toString` and `Object.prototype.toString`, which are different functions.

> ```
> console.log(Foo.toString == Foo.prototype.toString);
> ```

Is the same as `Function.prototype.toString == Object.prototype.toString`, since `Foo` is a function and inherits from `Function.prototype`, but `Foo.prototype` is an object, inheriting from `Object.prototype`.

> ```
> console.log(foo.toString === Foo.toString);
> ```

Same here. `foo` is an object, inheriting from `Foo.prototype`, which is an object.

---

These output `true`:

```
console.log(Foo.toString == Function.prototype.toString); // true
console.log(foo.toString === Object.prototype.toString); // true
console.log(foo.toString === Foo.prototype.toString); // true
```

The last one is `true` because the `foo` is created through the constructor function `Foo` and therefore inherits from `Foo`'s prototype, `Foo.prototype`.

Comment: I am a little bit confused.   Since Foo is an instance of Function, and I didn't override toString method, so when I reference to Foo.toString, it should search the prototype chain. Therefore Foo.prototype is searched. In this case, Foo.toString should be eaqual to Foo.prototype.toString, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You're not comparing the output of the methods, you're comparing the *references*. In javascript, the equal operators compare the references, except for primitive values (to keep it simple).

Example in code:

```
var foo = 5, bar = 5;
foo === bar // true

var foo = function() {}, bar = function() {};
foo === bar // false

// If you were to compare the outputs, the following would be true:
foo() === bar() // true
```

To come back to your example:

- `Foo.toString` is **not** the same reference as `Foo.prototype.toString`, but it is the same reference as `Function.prototype.toString`.
- `foo.toString` is not the same reference as `Foo.toString`. It is the same as `Foo.prototype.toString` (check `foo.toString === Foo.prototype.toString`, it is true).
- `foo` and `foo2` are two different objects. This is why their methods are not the same reference.

Some examples to illustrate:

```
Foo.toString === Function.prototype.toString // true
foo.toString === Foo.prototype.toString
```